# How to structure mongoose schema within a schema?

Tags: mongoose

I'm new to mongodb and I have a data model like such

```
{
    last_updated: Date.now(),
    csgo_items:[
        {name: 'name', price: 1},
        {name: 'name', price: 1},
        {name: 'name', price: 1}
    ]
}
```

I have a 'last_updated' and then a giant list of csgo items I store.

My question is. Do I need two schemas? One for the two properties on the outer layer and one schema for my csgo item model?

How would my schemas look if I did it this way?

I have my item schema like such.

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    price: Number,
    name: String,
});
```

Do I also need another schema to set for my outer schema like so?

```
var CsgoSchema = new Schema({
    last_updated: Date,
    item: Array,
});
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `item: [ItemSchema]`

Comment: So how would I add a Item to my CsgoSchema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have defined your item schemas as

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    price: Number,
    name: String
});
```

which has elements of the parent document items array, you can define the parent schema as

```
var CsgoSchema = new Schema({
    last_updated: Date,
    items: [ItemSchema]
});
```

When you want to add the items to the parent document array, you don't have to save each item individually first before adding it to the `Csgo` model, this is done whenever the top-level parent document is saved, for example

```
var Csgo = mongoose.model('Csgo', CsgoSchema);
var csgo = new Csgo({ 
    last_updated: new Date(),
    items: [
        {name: 'name1', price: 1},
        {name: 'name2', price: 2},
        {name: 'name3', price: 3}
    ] 
});

csgo.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err)
    console.log('Success!');
});
```

You can also use MongooseArray methods such as **[`push`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.push)**, **[`unshift`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.unshift)**, **[`addToSet`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet)** to add the items to the parent document. For instance:

```
var Csgo = mongoose.model('Csgo', CsgoSchema);
var csgo = new Csgo;

// add an item using push
csgo.items.push({name: 'name4', price: 4});
var csgo_item = csgo.items[0];
console.log(csgo_item); // { _id: '56e2bc9f61fb33583128be07', name: 'name4', price: 4 }
csgo_item.isNew; // true

csgo.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err)
    console.log('Success!');
});
```

You can also use the create method of MongooseArrays to add the items to the csgo document:.

```
var newcsgo = csgo.items.create({name: 'name', price: 1});
```

Comment: Thank you! Clear explanation. I'm building around these concepts. Much appreciated!